# order a dictionory of distict extracted values from queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

how to order a dictionory of distict values (extracted from queryset) based on count of occurrence?
For example:

```
query = self.my_queryset.filter(category='rock').values('first_name').distinct()
```

I want to order the resulting 'query' by the number occurrence of category 'rock'.

I am using postgresql as backend db, so open to ideas of doing this in postgres itself. :)
Thanks!!!

Comment: Dictionaries aren't an ordered data structure.

Comment: You should post the relevant code of your models and formulate more clear your question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

convert your query set into a list of values where each value is your model object.
then you can sort this list using python default sort function and pass a comparison function which compares two objects based on their count in your original query set.